# StringBuilder and byte conversion

Tags: c#, encoding, byte, stringbuilder

I have the following code:

```
StringBuilder data = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < bytes1; i++)
{ 
    data.Append("a"); 
}
byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
```

But I get this error:

> ```
> cannot convert from 'System.Text.StringBuilder' to 'char[]'
> The best overloaded method match for 'System.Text.Encoding.GetBytes(char[])'
> has some invalid arguments
> ```

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The following code will fix your issue.

```
StringBuilder data = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < bytes1; i++)
{ data.Append("a"); }
byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data.ToString());
```

The problem is that you are passing a `StringBuilder` to the `GetBytes` function when you need to passing the string result from the `StringBuilder`.

Answer (score 15):

GetBytes doesn't accept a StringBuilder as a parameter.  Use a string with data.ToString()

```
byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data.ToString());
```

Answer (score 9):

ASCII is not a good encoding choice for text in this century.  Web and mobile applications should be at least using UTF-8, and any other type of application that is supposed to work in a globalized business or social networking environment should too.

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < iLength; ++ i)
    builder.Append("a");
byte[] bytesFromBuilder = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.ToString());
```

Answer (score 6):

Please try this. StringBuilder is object.. from there, you have to get string value as follow.

```
byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data.ToString());
```

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data.ToString().ToCharArray());
```

Comment: No need to explicitly convert the string to an array, GetBytes() will accept a string.